# Xcode release build configuration reflects outdated git branch

Tags: ios, xcode, git-branch, info.plist, run-script

When building my app with **Xcode** `debug` *build configuration* I am seeing my most recently updated **git** *branch*.

When building my app with **Xcode** `release` *build configuration* I am seeing an outdated **git** *branch*.

How do I build my app in **Xcode** `release` *build configuration* with the proper **git** *branch*?

Comment: Guessing there is something I am missing in Target's Info.plist or Build Settings?

Comment: or maybe add a Build Phases Run Script?